# Filter JSON with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JSON array containing several objects. I would like to return objects containing a certain value. For example, I would like to return

```
[
    service_wog: {
        count: 48,
        popular: false,
        code: 33,
        price: 20,
        id: 76,
        service: 'WOG',
        slug: 'wog'
      },
      service_gojoy: {
        count: 48,
        popular: false,
        code: 33,
        price: 20,
        id: 77,
        service: 'GoJoy',
        slug: 'gojoy'
          }
]
```

How do I return the object that contains 'gojoy' in slug?

I tried the following way:

```
let u = Object.values(a);
u.filter(i => i.slug === 'gojoy');
```

It doesn't seem to be working... Did I misunderstand how the `filter()` works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it seems that you're using `filter` correctly.
However, what are you using as an input:

```
[
  service_wog: {
      count: 48,
      popular: false,
      code: 33,
      price: 20,
      id: 76,
      service: 'WOG',
      slug: 'wog'
  },
  service_gojoy: {
      count: 48,
      popular: false,
      code: 33,
      price: 20,
      id: 77,
      service: 'GoJoy',
      slug: 'gojoy'
  }
]
```

it's not a valid array, but an object.

So instead of `[` and `]` - `{` and `}` should be used:

```
{
  service_wog: {
      count: 48,
      popular: false,
      code: 33,
      price: 20,
      id: 76,
      service: 'WOG',
      slug: 'wog'
  },
  service_gojoy: {
      count: 48,
      popular: false,
      code: 33,
      price: 20,
      id: 77,
      service: 'GoJoy',
      slug: 'gojoy'
  }
}
```

So eventually:

```js
const a = {
  service_wog: {
      count: 48,
      popular: false,
      code: 33,
      price: 20,
      id: 76,
      service: 'WOG',
      slug: 'wog'
  },
  service_gojoy: {
      count: 48,
      popular: false,
      code: 33,
      price: 20,
      id: 77,
      service: 'GoJoy',
      slug: 'gojoy'
  }
}

let u = Object.values(a);
console.log(u.filter(i => i.slug === 'gojoy'));
```